# Управление заливкой в boxplot'e

Tags: r, статистика, статический-анализ

Необходимо сделать ящики с усами показывающие зависимость распределений смертности от меланомы от расположения штата США в береговой зоне. Открытый датасет USmelanoma пакета HSAUR3. Код ниже дает следующий график.

```
 ggplot(data = USmelanoma, aes(x=ocean,y=mortality)) + theme_grey()+ 
        scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1')+
        geom_boxplot(aes(fill=ocean))+
        theme(legend.position = 'none')+
        labs(x = 'Океан', y = 'Смертность на 1 млн. чел.')+ 
        scale_x_discrete(labels = c('Нет', 'Да'))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как поменять местами цвета раскраски ящиков, чтобы "Нет" был бирюзовым, а "Да" - карминным. С помощью какой функции вообще управлять такими цветами? В доках не нашел инфу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решается это заменой палитры на палитру Брюэра.

```
gg_box <- ggplot(data = USmelanoma, aes(x=ocean,y=mortality,fill=ocean)) + theme_grey() + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Pastel2')+   # Вот тут выбирается вторая пастельная палитра
    geom_boxplot()+
    theme(legend.position = 'none')+
    labs(x = 'Океан', y = 'Смертность на 1 млн. чел.')+ scale_x_discrete(labels = c('Нет', 'Да'))
```